# Ubuntu 18.04 -Budgie won't connect to network before login

Tags: boot, networking, budgie

I'm using a (old) desktop using to run Budgie 18.04, since it is old and LAN is not available nearby, I'm using a wifi dongle.

The problem is that it is getting connected to network only AFTER logging in ( not good since intended to be accessed headless ). At start I thought it has something to do with SSH that didn't went through, but also `ping` failed.
only after connecting it to LAN - everything went well: SSH, VNC and ping.

How can I get it connected for such purpose when using a wifi dongle that will get connected after boot without login ? I cant only think of automatic login to solve this issue, but I thing it is wrong, security wise.

appriciate any help
Guy

Comment: did you get any closer to figuring this out? I have this problem too

Comment: Remove budgie solved the problem

Comment: I am on bionic.. to be honest I am disgusted at Ubuntu 18.04.. 
 1 .`cloud.init` `.cfg` overwrites netplan's `.yaml` which itself ignores the `/etc/resolv.conf` nameservers because of a sloppy symlink.. so for using static ethernet I have to have a 14 step 2 page README on how to make it even `ping google`... and now the ethernet doesn't come up until login.. wtf is up with it?